# Scrape Data from an Interactive plot Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a list of 57 properties along with their URLs. I want to scrape the data point in a plot that shows the price of the property for a 10-year period. I have collected the data manually by selecting the Network tab in Inspect. This is the cite URL: `https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-Pointe-Villa-Rica-GA-30180/60118739_zpid/`. The plot can be seen under `Zestimate history and details` tab on the webpage. Can someone please guide me on how I can make this process automated so that it automatically scrapes the data by using the URL? I have thousands of URLs so that's why I want to automate the whole scraping process.

[image]

I copied the responses manually and form them in a data frame like below. Can someone please help me?

Data frame:

```
   Zestimate                       URL                             Date
0   390166  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2013-10-31
1   400633  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2013-11-30
2   404064  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2013-12-31
3   382856  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2014-01-31
4   351772  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2014-02-28
... ... ... ...
116 678700  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2023-06-30
117 670500  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2023-07-31
118 673700  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2023-08-31
119 682100  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2023-09-30
120 674100  https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-P...   2023-10-31
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# The JSON data you provided
data_json = '''
{
    "data": {
        "property": {
            "homeValueChartData": [
                {
                    "points": [
                        {"x": 1383202800000, "y": 390166},
                        {"x": 1385798400000, "y": 400633},
                        {"x": 1388476800000, "y": 404064},
                        {"x": 1391155200000, "y": 382856},
                        {"x": 1393574400000, "y": 351772},
                        {"x": 1396249200000, "y": 341278},
                        {"x": 1398841200000, "y": 360731},
                        {"x": 1401519600000, "y": 361093},
                        {"x": 1404111600000, "y": 361034},
                        {"x": 1406790000000, "y": 357738},
                        {"x": 1409468400000, "y": 355825},
                        {"x": 1412060400000, "y": 363885},
                        {"x": 1414738800000, "y": 365830},
                        {"x": 1417334400000, "y": 359472},
                        {"x": 1420012800000, "y": 364893},
                        {"x": 1422691200000, "y": 384514},
                        {"x": 1425110400000, "y": 375939},
                        {"x": 1427785200000, "y": 382934},
                        {"x": 1430377200000, "y": 378196},
                        {"x": 1433055600000, "y": 405560},
                        {"x": 1435647600000, "y": 406905},
                        {"x": 1438326000000, "y": 401756},
                        {"x": 1441004400000, "y": 395902},
                        {"x": 1443596400000, "y": 398292},
                        {"x": 1446274800000, "y": 375829},
                        {"x": 1448870400000, "y": 370703},
                        {"x": 1451548800000, "y": 370703},
                        {"x": 1454227200000, "y": 390901},
                        {"x": 1456732800000, "y": 391154},
                        {"x": 1459407600000, "y": 393683},
                        {"x": 1461999600000, "y": 395847},
                        {"x": 1464678000000, "y": 398152},
                        {"x": 1467270000000, "y": 398697},
                        {"x": 1469948400000, "y": 402019},
                        {"x": 1472626800000, "y": 404413},
                        {"x": 1475218800000, "y": 401915},
                        {"x": 1477897200000, "y": 404460},
                        {"x": 1480492800000, "y": 408949},
                        {"x": 1483171200000, "y": 413256},
                        {"x": 1485849600000, "y": 410720},
                        {"x": 1488268800000, "y": 427205},
                        {"x": 1490943600000, "y": 425667},
                        {"x": 1493535600000, "y": 427310},
                        {"x": 1496214000000, "y": 430876},
                        {"x": 1498806000000, "y": 434657},
                        {"x": 1501484400000, "y": 442292},
                        {"x": 1504162800000, "y": 446863},
                        {"x": 1506754800000, "y": 457602},
                        {"x": 1509433200000, "y": 462018},
                        {"x": 1512028800000, "y": 461651},
                        {"x": 1514707200000, "y": 464657},
                        {"x": 1517385600000, "y": 468263},
                        {"x": 1519804800000, "y": 469469},
                        {"x": 1522479600000, "y": 473995},
                        {"x": 1525071600000, "y": 471393},
                        {"x": 1527750000000, "y": 470395},
                        {"x": 1530342000000, "y": 470107},
                        {"x": 1533020400000, "y": 455788},
                        {"x": 1535698800000, "y": 440119},
                        {"x": 1538290800000, "y": 440119},
                        {"x": 1540969200000, "y": 441785},
                        {"x": 1543564800000, "y": 500143},
                        {"x": 1546243200000, "y": 507382},
                        {"x": 1548921600000, "y": 482134},
                        {"x": 1551340800000, "y": 470097},
                        {"x": 1554015600000, "y": 461770},
                        {"x": 1556607600000, "y": 465657},
                        {"x": 1559286000000, "y": 470224},
                        {"x": 1561878000000, "y": 476407},
                        {"x": 1564556400000, "y": 475415},
                        {"x": 1567234800000, "y": 478638},
                        {"x": 1569826800000, "y": 478777},
                        {"x": 1572505200000, "y": 481885},
                        {"x": 1575100800000, "y": 481868},
                        {"x": 1577779200000, "y": 427683},
                        {"x": 1580457600000, "y": 429632},
                        {"x": 1582963200000, "y": 433207},
                        {"x": 1585638000000, "y": 443646},
                        {"x": 1588230000000, "y": 437506},
                        {"x": 1590908400000, "y": 433391},
                        {"x": 1593500400000, "y": 435165},
                        {"x": 1596178800000, "y": 436146},
                        {"x": 1598857200000, "y": 450041},
                        {"x": 1601449200000, "y": 470654},
                        {"x": 1604127600000, "y": 471759},
                        {"x": 1606723200000, "y": 474268},
                        {"x": 1609401600000, "y": 481260},
                        {"x": 1612080000000, "y": 495559},
                        {"x": 1614499200000, "y": 492742},
                        {"x": 1617174000000, "y": 499574},
                        {"x": 1619766000000, "y": 556833},
                        {"x": 1622444400000, "y": 601761},
                        {"x": 1625036400000, "y": 592400},
                        {"x": 1627714800000, "y": 588800},
                        {"x": 1630393200000, "y": 595300},
                        {"x": 1632985200000, "y": 602700},
                        {"x": 1635663600000, "y": 604600},
                        {"x": 1638259200000, "y": 619100},
                        {"x": 1640937600000, "y": 630400},
                        {"x": 1643616000000, "y": 633700},
                        {"x": 1646035200000, "y": 637800},
                        {"x": 1648710000000, "y": 648200},
                        {"x": 1651302000000, "y": 655100},
                        {"x": 1653980400000, "y": 658300},
                        {"x": 1656572400000, "y": 663600},
                        {"x": 1659250800000, "y": 655900},
                        {"x": 1661929200000, "y": 652600},
                        {"x": 1664521200000, "y": 648300},
                        {"x": 1667199600000, "y": 642200},
                        {"x": 1669795200000, "y": 632200},
                        {"x": 1672473600000, "y": 622200},
                        {"x": 1675152000000, "y": 617300},
                        {"x": 1677571200000, "y": 624800},
                        {"x": 1680246000000, "y": 634800},
                        {"x": 1682838000000, "y": 640500},
                        {"x": 1685516400000, "y": 665400},
                        {"x": 1688108400000, "y": 678700},
                        {"x": 1690786800000, "y": 670500},
                        {"x": 1693465200000, "y": 673700},
                        {"x": 1696057200000, "y": 682100},
                        {"x": 1696402800000, "y": 674100}
                    ],
                    "name": "This home"
                },
                {
                    "points": [
                        {"x": 1451548800000, "y": 390000},
                        {"x": 1588575600000, "y": 450000},
                        {"x": 1588575600000, "y": 450000}
                    ],
                    "name": "Sale"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "extensions": {}
}
'''

# Define the URL for the property
property_url = "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/1053-Lake-Pointe-Villa-Rica-GA-30180/60118739_zpid/"

# Parse the JSON data
data = json.loads(data_json)

# Extract the "y" values
home_value_data = data["data"]["property"]["homeValueChartData"][0]["points"]
y_values = [entry["y"] for entry in home_value_data]

# Create a date range starting from October 2013 to match the available data points
start_date = pd.to_datetime("2013-10-01")
end_date = pd.to_datetime("2023-10-01")
date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, periods=len(y_values), freq='M')

# Create a DataFrame with "y" values, the associated URL, and the date column
df = pd.DataFrame({"Zestimate": y_values, "URL": [property_url] * len(y_values), "Date": date_range})

# Display the DataFrame
df
```